# Multiprocessing using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run the same process many times, at the same time. The issue I am having right now is that the program only runs one at a time and waits until that process is done to start a new one.

I am not sure how to have them running side by side at the same time.

```
pool = Pool(processes=2)
item1 = pool.apply_async(run_bot(item_keyword, PROXY))
item2 = pool.apply_async(run_bot(item_keyword, PROXY))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Why are you passing the arguments this way?

Answer (score 0):

it could happen if both of ur bots' browsers use the same **user-data-dir** *path*

there's an argument for chrome:

```
--user-data-dir=path
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might need this, this is how I solved it:

```
instance_number = len(proxy_list)

for i in range(instance_number):
    item_keyword = item_keywords_list[i]
    PROXY = proxy_list[i]
    instance[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_bot, args=(item_keyword, PROXY, year, month, day, hour, minute))

for i in range(0, instance_number, 1):
    instance[i].start()

for i in range(0, instance_number, 1):
    instance[i].join()
```

You don't need the

```
for in in range(instance_number):
```

I did it that way so I can scale this easier in the future.